# Counting Numbers, Uppercase Letters, Lowercase Letters and Spaces with own Function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, counting

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I can't seem to find the solution to my mistake.
So I got to define a function "processSentence" that skims the sentence and counts numbers, upper, lower cases and spaces. This is what I got so far and I'm just not getting any further.

```
sentence = "3 big frogs decorate the christmas tree with 22 bananas"

def processSentence(sentence): 
    spaces = 0
    numbers = 0
    uppers = 0
    lowers = 0

    for character in sentence:
      if character in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
        numbers += 1

    for character in sentence:
      if character in ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]:
        lowers += 1

    for character in sentence:
      if character in ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]:
        uppers += 1

    for character in sentence:
      if character in [" "]:
        spaces += 1

    report = f"The sentence had {numbers}, {uppers}, {lowers} and {spaces}"

    print(report)
```

Comment: I'm sure if you search for each of these on here as separate questions (find uppercase characters in string, etc.. )you'll find good answers...

Comment: The code as posted above is incorrectly indented. and you never call 'processSentence'

Comment: You say you're getting a mistake, but you don't say what the mistake _is_.

Comment: Your for loops should be indented, because they belong to the function. You also need to return the numbers from the function. Finally, don't forget to call the function.

Comment: `if character in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` Those digits should be in quotes, just like the letters.

Comment: By the way you can say `if x in "abc"` instead of `if x in ["a", "b", "c"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use one loop for every counter, so probably this will help you to make your code more readable and easier.

```
sentence = "3 big frogs decorate the christmas tree with 22 bananas"

def processSentence(sentence):
    spaces = 0
    numbers = 0
    uppers = 0
    lowers = 0

    for character in sentence:
      if character in '0123456789':
        numbers += 1
      elif character.islower():
        lowers += 1
    
      elif character.isupper():
        uppers += 1

      elif character == ' ':
        spaces += 1

    report = f"The sentence had numbers:{numbers}, Upper case:{uppers}, Lower Case:{lowers} and Spaces{spaces}"

    print(report)


processSentence(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the string module

```
import string

sentence = "3 big frogs decorate the christmas tree with 22 bananas"


def processSentence(sentence):
    # just storing the character sets, avoiding doing it in each loop of the for-cycle
    lowercase_characters = string.ascii_lowercase
    uppercase_characters = string.ascii_uppercase
    digit_characters = string.digits

    spaces = 0
    numbers = 0
    lowers = 0
    uppers = 0
    # maybe use some variable to count residual characters?
    residual = 0

    for character in sentence:
        if character in lowercase_characters:
            lowers += 1
        elif character in uppercase_characters:
            uppers += 1
        elif character in digit_characters:
            numbers += 1
        elif character == " ":
            spaces += 1
        else:
            residual += 1
        report = f"The sentence had numbers:{numbers}, Upper case:{uppers}, Lower Case:{lowers} and Spaces{spaces}"
        print(report)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    processSentence(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "3 big frogs decorate the christmas tree with 22 bananas"

def processSentence(sentence):
    spaces = 0
    numbers = 0
    uppers = 0
    lowers = 0

    for character in sentence:
        if character in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
            numbers = numbers + 1

    for character in sentence:
        if character in ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
                         "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]:
            lowers = lowers + 1

    for character in sentence:
        if character in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
                         "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]:
            uppers = uppers + 1

    for character in sentence:
        if character in [" "]:
            spaces = spaces + 1

    report = f"The sentence had numbers:{numbers}, Upper case:{uppers}, Lower Case:{lowers} and Spaces{spaces}"

    print(report)


processSentence(sentence)
```

You had the make the numbers array as a string and the variable names and typos